# Как при использовании imagestringup увеличить размер шрифта?

Tags: шрифты, php

Привет всем.

Как при использовании imagestringup увеличить размер шрифта?

```
$font = imageloadfont('/var/www/***/data/www/***/font/arial.ttf');
$color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagestringup($image, $font, 455, 80, 'TEXT', $color );
```

Comment: @innot20, а может, использовать [imagettftext()][1]? Там и угол можно задать, как и в imagestringup(), и размер шрифта.

   [1]:http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagettftext.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$logo_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255, 255, 255, 0);
ImageTTFtext($image, 9.5, 90, 464, 94, $logo_color,  "/var/www/---/data/www/---/fonts/arial.ttf", "TEXT");
```